# swift 4.0 Alamofire 4.0+ swiftyjson post request with URL Encode (data=JsonData)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift4, urlencode

i need to get response from a .post request for a custom parameters with alamofire.

```
Method          : POST
Content Type    : application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept          : application/json
Parameter       : URL Encode (data=JsonData)
```

the post request must be somthing like :

```
data={
    "command": "checkemail",
    "email": "something@something.org",
    "time": "20180315221734",
}
```

exactly like that , with the "data = {}" thingy

im expecting a return because its for the validation for email

its something like

```
let json = Json(datafromnetwork)

if (json["emailexist"].stringvalue == "1"){
//do segue
}else{
//give alert
}
```

my friend suggest to use callbacks but i still searching for a better answer . because my friends callbacks cant return anything until my apps is terminated. any suggestion is welcome
thanks :)

Comment: What is the url of request? can you please tell so I can help you

Comment: its a .net backend.. i dont think posting the url will help tho :(

Comment: how can I help then

Comment: callback will be good approach